# How to load resources in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to load a file containing 3D geometry using Away3D.  It's basically an XML file that contains some relative paths to image files that also need to be loaded.

```
var loader:Loader3D = new Loader3D(true, null);
var token:AssetLoaderToken = loader.load(new URLRequest("res/room.dae"));
token.addEventListener(AssetEvent.ASSET_COMPLETE, onAssetComplete);
```

Anyhow, I'm having trouble figuring out where to place these files so that my program is able to find them.  If I just place them in the same directory as the actionscript files, they aren't copied to the debug directory and my program can't find them when run.  Also, when I finally publish my program I want to make sure these files are bundled along with the rest of my SWF.

What's the right way to set up my paths for doing this?

Comment: It depends, what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Adobe FlashBuilder.  It looks like I just need to manually copy the files into the build directory.  I'm thinking I can do this with an ant script.

Comment: Create a `package` called "assets (or whatever) in your FB project and drag the assets into that. Then use that as your relative path. But you **must** do it through FB – not just put them in the same directory using the desktop (Finder or whatever OS you are on).

Comment: You can also easily link external resources (a folder somewhere on hard drive). Those resources will be copied to the bin-debug folder and exported along your build. FB will keep an eye on it and update everything automatically when needed. Very handy when you work on multiple project sharing same or some resources.